# Argument list too long - Apache

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-web-services, permissions, apache2

I'm following this tutorial on deploying an wordpress application inside an AWS instance  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/hosting-wordpress.html and I get an error when I do

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-10-1-73 ]$ find /var/www -type f -exec sudo chmod 0664 {} +
sudo: unable to execute /bin/chmod: Argument list too long
sudo: unable to execute /bin/chmod: Argument list too long
```

What is the root problem of this error?

Answer (score 5):

So you are trying to pass to many arguments to chmod, you could be running out of stack space. This is a limit you can set on linux using ulimit, but personally I would just modify the command

```
find /var/www -type f -exec sudo chmod 0664 {} \;
```

The difference is that with the + you are trying change the permissions of all the files at once, with \; you are setting the permissions one file at a time